# Android Base Adapter not writing to text view

Tags: android

I have a problem, the class DataListAdapter is not writing to the text views given to it, leaving the text views blank. The activity which this concerns is thus:

```
public class LoadData extends Activity
{
    ListView dataList;
    MachineDataAdapter adapter;
    Context context;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.load_data);

        dataList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.machineList);

        //Log.d("intent", getIntent().getStringExtra("json"));
        dataList.setAdapter(new DataListAdapter(getIntent().getStringExtra("json")));
        context = this;

    }

    public void backClicked(View view)
    {
        Intent mainMenu = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainMenu.class);
        startActivity(mainMenu);
    }

    public void launchScan(View view)
    {
        Intent scanLaunch = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ScanTag.class);
        startActivity(scanLaunch);
    }

    class DataListAdapter extends BaseAdapter
    {
        private JSONObject json;
        private Iterator<String> keys;
        LayoutInflater inflater;

        public DataListAdapter(String jsonString)
        {
            try
            {
                json = new JSONObject(jsonString);
            } catch (JSONException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            keys = json.keys();
            inflater = getLayoutInflater();

        }


        public int getCount() {
            return json.names().length();
        }

        public Object getItem(int arg0) {
            return null;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int i, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


            if(convertView == null)
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.machine_data_row, parent, false);

            TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.machineRowTitle);
            TextView data = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.machineRowData);

            if(keys.hasNext())
            {
                String key = keys.next();
                String value = null;
                try
                {
                    value = json.getString(key);
                } catch (JSONException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Log.d("json", key);
                title.setText(key);
                data.setText(value);
            }

            return (convertView);
        }
    }



}
```

And here is machine_data_row.xml for completeness:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/machineRowTitle"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#0000FF"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             />

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/machineRowData"
            android:textColor="#5C002E"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           />

</LinearLayout>
```

The json works just fine, I am successfully printing each key using Log.d. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: This is the json data:

```
{"a":"b","c":"d","e":"f"}
```

Comment: pleas post your json content

Comment: I have amended the post with the json data as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea why this worked, but getting the key using `key = json.names().getString(i);`
Solved the issue.

Comment: you cannot use an iterator in an adapter. an iterator gives you each item in order, once only. an adapter can require the view for any item, in any order, any number of times.

Comment: also, you should be aware that the keys in a json object have no guarantee as too their order.

Comment: Yup, I downloaded the source of JSONObject and modified it to use a LinkedHashMap, and now it works great. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Typically I like to do something like this in the `getView`:

```
if (convertView == null) {
          LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
          row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
          //Make sure the textview exists in this xml
} else {
          row = convertView;
}
TextView titleLabel = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.titleText);
```

Comment: This works, but it only fills a single row, which is really odd.